# Is it possible to auto generate and superimpose Frame# over images imported into video edit?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I imported a series of images into the video editor and I would like the rendered output to show the frame number, or better yet the file name of each image, on each image. Is there a way to automatically generate that number? 
Why do you ask? The still images are used in reports and frame numbers or file names would make it easier for my customers to find the desired image.
  Thank you,
    Paul

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's possible.

You just have to open the **Metadata** section in Render Tab of Properties panel, check **Stamp output**, adjust the size and colors, and check the **Seq. strip** box (uncheck all other if not needed), and it will print the filename of the current rendered image on the top right corner of the output.

[image]

[image]